# Python parsing JSON with escaped double quotes

Tags: python, json, encoding

Consider this valid json:

`{"a": 1, "b": "{\"c\":2}"}`

Python's `json` module throws when I try to parse it - it looks like the `\"` is throwing it off:

```
json.loads('{"a": 1, "b": "{\"c\":2}"}')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 381, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 15 (char 14)
```

Is there any way to parse this in Python, either using the `json` module or some other module like `ujson`?

Answer (score 4):

Actually it doesn't matter with escaped double quotes. See my test:

```
>>> json.loads('{"a": 1, "b": "{\"c\":2}"}')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 318, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 343, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 359, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 18 (char 17)

>>> json.loads('{"a": 1, "b": "{"c":2}"}')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 318, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 343, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 359, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 18 (char 17)

>>> json.loads('{"a": 1, "b": {"c":2}}')
{'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 2}}

>>> json.loads('{"a": 1, "b": {\"c\":2}}')
{'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 2}}

>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

Inside a quoted string, `\"` is treated the same as a regular quote:

```
>>> '{"a": 1, "b": "{\"c\":2}"}'
'{"a": 1, "b": "{"c":2}"}'
```

As a result, your string is *not* valid JSON.

You need to escape the backslashes as well, so that they are sent to `loads`. You can see this by encoding your desired dictionary with `dumps`:

```
>>> json.dumps({"a": 1, "b": "{\"c\": 2}"})
'{"a": 1, "b": "{\\"c\\": 2}"}'

>>> json.loads('{"a": 1, "b": "{\\"c\\": 2}"}')
{u'a': 1, u'b': u'{"c": 2}'}
```

Comment: Or use a raw string literal: `json.loads(r'{"a": 1, "b": "{\"c\":2}"}')`.