# How to parse escaped Double Quote in JSON String

Tags: python, json

From an API I am getting following JSON String which I want to convert into python dict.

```
{
    "title":"size_fit_desc",
    "description":"\u003Cp\u003ERegular Fit\u003Cbr \u002F\u003EThe model (height 5'8\", chest 33\" and waist 28\") is wearing a size M.\u003C\u002Fp\u003E"
}
```

If I try to load it using `json.loads()` It gives me an error

> > ValueError: Expecting property name: line 3 column 97 (char 136)

However If I try to use this string as raw string then it works.

```
s = r"""{
        "title":"size_fit_desc",
        description":"\u003Cp\u003ERegular Fit\u003Cbr \u002F\u003EThe model (height 5'8\", chest 33\" and waist 28\") is wearing a size M.\u003C\u002Fp\u003E"
}"""
```

I think there an issue with an escaping at `(height 5'8\", chest 33\"`.

How can I assign this json string from API to python string object and convert it into dict using `json.loads(s)` ?

json.loads(json.dumps(s)) does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: How to escape double quote inside json string value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40150405/python-how-to-escape-double-quote-inside-json-string-value)

Comment: If `json.loads` won't load it, it isn't valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

A quick test in console with this seems to proove that the doube-quotes should be double-escaped (`\\`).
The answer you are looking for is [Python: How to escape double quote inside json string value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40150405/python-how-to-escape-double-quote-inside-json-string-value)

```
>>> tempStr = '{"title" : "foo", "desc": "foo\\"bar\\""}'
>>> temp2 = json.loads(tempStr)
>>> temp2
{'title': 'foo', 'desc': 'foo"bar"'}
```

This is sometwhat the same answer as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997029/escape-double-quotes-for-json-in-python) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728380/python-parsing-json-with-escaped-double-quotes)

---

Using replacement:

```
>>> tmpstr = '{"title" : "foo", "desc": "foo\"bar\""}'
>>> tempStr.replace('"', '\"')
'{"title" : "foo", "desc": "foo\\"bar\\""}'
```

Comment: I am still confused. How did you convert '{"title" : "foo", "desc": "foo\"bar\""}' into '{"title" : "foo", "desc": "foo\\"bar\\""}'

Comment: I did it by hand for the sake of explanation. The refrenced SO answer explains what you can do to perform the conversion programmatically.

Comment: I tried but it does not give desired output.

`>>> tempStr = '{"title" : "foo", "desc": "foo\\"bar\\""}'`
`>>> tempStr = '{"title" : "foo", "desc": "foo\"bar\""}'`
`>>> print tempStr.replace('"', '\\"')`
`{\"title\" : \"foo\", \"desc\": \"foo\"bar\"\"}`
>>> 
`

Comment: You need to focus on what the `replace` is supposed to do.